# FBX export from blender deforms the object

Tags: animation, rigging, export

I have a rigged and animated model and I want to export it from Blender to use it in c4d, but it doesn’t work. I tried to bake the animation but no results. Maybe I’m doing it wrong. I don’t use Blender. What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: With this little information, finding the answer is a lucky guess game. It would help if you could upload your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and [edit] your post to embed the link. In the meantime, could you check if the scales and rotations applied on the mesh and armature objects? Do you have a root bone at the top of the whole hierarchy? Are all vertices weighted to at least one bone, and the weights normalized?